# How to check if body in fetch POST has sent to API in react native?

Tags: react-native, post, ios-simulator, fetch, expo

I am building a react native app and got this following error. I want to send inputted message, email, and name to API, but it's not showing any result in API.

Here is the code:

```
fetch('localserverusingIPaddress', {
                method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                  },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    name: this.state.name,
                    email: this.state.email,
                    message: this.state.message,
                }),
            })
            .then((response)=> {console.warn(response.json())})
            //{
            //  if (response.status){
            //      return response.json();
            //  }
                // console.warn(response.json())
                // return response.json();
            //})
                //console.warn(response);
                //response.json()
                //console.warn(JSON.parse(response))})
             .then((responseData)=>{
                this.showAlert();
                console.warn(responseData);
                return responseData;
             })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.warn(error);
            });
```

However, when I try to check the inputted texts in iOS 
simulator, it's showing the value. It's also showing the values when I post data to API directly with postman. So I start to think that the body was failed to pass to API.

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening and how to fix this? Thank you so much, I'm facing this problem for several weeks...

Comment: what's your log message either in `.then` block or `catch` block?

Comment: Is `localserverusingIPaddress` in first line of code just a placeholder here? What is actually logged in console when you run this?

Comment: @mostafizrahman the first `.then` giving me this message `{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}` , while the second `.then` giving me `undefined` message. the error in `catch` block didn't show anything..

Comment: @UzairA. yes, it's only a placeholder, basically I use my IP address for the fetch url, not localhost.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to make sure if your iOS simulator is actually able to make requests to your localhost or not. If it can't reach your local network, it must throw some kind of connectivity error. However, from your comment above, it seems that is not an issue.

Try this code:

```
let url = 'localserverusingIPaddress';
let requestObject = {
    name: this.state.name,
    email: this.state.email,
    message: this.state.message
};

try {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(requestObject)
    });

    responseJson = await response.json();
    console.log(responseJson);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);    
  }
```

Try this and see what is the logged output.

Easiest way to see if the request has actually reached your API is from the API end itself. Your server must have some sort of event logging implemented. See what happens there when you make a request from Postman and compare its output with what happens when you make a request from the app.

Comment: thank you so much for your response.. I tried to use the code you give and got this log message `{"status": true, "msg": "The request has been sent"}` and basically this message is the same just like in the Postman. But still, the inputted text is only showing an empty message, no values at all to API..

Comment: The log message above is being sent by the API itself. So it means that the request has successfully reached the API. I don't understand what you mean by `the inputted text is only showing an empty message`. Is there something you want to show in the React Native app? What the API does after receiving request from the app has nothing to do with React Native now. You should look at the API's implementation to see what's happening.

Comment: Yeah so this module is basically has a function to send an inputted message from the app to an email.. but when I checked it on the email, the message, email, and also name are empty.. that is why I really confused.

Comment: So the API is called and e-mail is sent, but all the text strings are empty? You can do `console.log(requestObject)` before calling `fetch()` to see what request is being sent to the API. Also, is the request from Postman successful? If yes then closely compare both requests to see what is happening.

Comment: yes, correct. I tried to do `console.log(requestObject)` as you told and it's giving me exactly the same value as I input. However the email is still empty, not showing the values. And yes, if I post it directly from Postman it's also succeed, the only different is the sent email showing the values.